# How to make authorization with Java?

Tags: java, web-applications

I use Geoserver Manager library to work with Geoserver by REST.
Its use Geoserver login/pass to work. So from client i send login/pass and its work and create objects:

```
GeoServerRESTReader reader = new GeoServerRESTReader(urlL, login, pass);
GeoServerRESTPublisher publisher = new GeoServerRESTPublisher(url, login, pass);
```

Its nice but i gonna send logn/pass from clien each time.
How to make that send login/pass from client only once? I mean how to make it correctly? I see several ways to do it:
1. Create `reader` and `publisher` only once and remove it when send command from client.
2. Save login/pass in variable on client and send it each time to server.
3. Save login/pass in file or variable on server and create `reader` and `publisher` each time.
Can you tell me what way more correct and how to realize it?